# Error in reading from a .txt file in c++

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //reading the text file
    ifstream inputFile("testfile1.txt");
    inputFile.open("testfile1.txt");
    while(!inputFile.eof())
    //eof till end of file, reads the txt till end of file
    {
        string str;
        getline(inputFile,str);
        cout <<str<< endl;

    }
        inputFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

// The problem that i am having is that it doesn not read the file or anything in it. Doing nothing it says Program ended with exit code: 0. Could anyone check the mistake in the code

Comment: Unrelated: you opened the file twice ?

Comment: No, it's very much related. Opening the same file twice is the bug here. The second `open()` fails, and sets the `fail` bit on the file stream. The second bug here is the popular [while eof bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik apparently the code has morphed, because a few minutes ago the logic in the loop conditional was the contra-positive of what it is now. Go figure.

Comment: Well, even though it's morphed it is still wrong. But that's just one of the two bugs.

Comment: Is this the **real** code you are asking about? Since you have changed it significantly since initially posting it, that's a valid question.

Comment: Yeah,  I was so focused on the other two bugs, I didn't think about the first. Good catch. Post that up so I can uptick it =P.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Could you be specific why is it wrong ? 
while(!inputFile.eof()) is so that all the elements in the .txt is read until the end of the file. It is not for opening the file. I dont see how is it opened twice?

Comment: @user45524 Throw out the `.open` call. You already opened the file with the constructor. After that, [heed the link Sam provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

First Bug: You are opening the input file twice. Per the C++ standard, regarding the behavior of your second open request (the direct call to the `open` member):

**C++11 § 27.9.1.9 [ifstream.members/3]**

> `void open(const char* s, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in);`
>
> Effects: Calls `rdbuf()->open(s, mode | ios_base::in)`. If that function
>   does not return a null pointer calls clear(), **otherwise calls
>   setstate(failbit)** (which may throw ios_base::failure (27.5.5.4)).

which therefore asks the question, what does `rdbuf()->open(...)` do ? Well, a `std::ifstream` uses a `filebuf` for it's buffering, and once again, per the standard:

**C++11 §27.9.1.4 [filebuf.members/2]**

> `basic_filebuf<charT,traits>* open(const char* s, ios_base::openmode mode);`
>
> Effects: **If `is_open()` != false, returns a null pointer**. Otherwise, initializes the filebuf as required. ...

In short, your double-open is putting your stream into a fail-state, which means all data-related operations with it are going to fail outright from that point on.

---

Second Bug: Improper use of .eof in a loop conditional expression. you'll run into this once you fix the first bug. The reasons this is not being done correctly are explained in the following question far better than I can explain it here.

[Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Suffice it to say, check your IO operations, not just the eof-state of the stream. Get into that habit and stick with it.

Fixing both, your code can literally be reduced to simply this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputFile("testfile1.txt");
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(inputFile, str))
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Obviously if you're shooting for more robust code, you probably want to perform some error handling in there, something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputFile("testfile1.txt");
    if (!inputFile)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(inputFile, str))
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to read a file according to this [article](https://gehrcke.de/2011/06/reading-files-in-c-using-ifstream-dealing-correctly-with-badbit-failbit-eofbit-and-perror/)!
The problem in your code it seems that you are using an IDE and it cannot find the path you are giving to ifstream so try to give a full path to the file. Hope it can help u.

```
string line;
ifstream f("/YOUPARTH/testfile1.txt");
if (!f.is_open())
    perror("error while opening file");
while(getline(f, line)) {
   cout << line << endl;
}
if (f.bad())
    perror("error while reading file");
return 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Translate the while statement: "While inputFile is at End Of File" .. you want the negation of that.

Comment: sorry i actually had (!inputfile.eof) but it still does not do anything. Could there be a problem in reading the file ?